# Find and Classify Singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

> > Find and classify the singularities of the following functions in $\mathbb{C}$:
> >
> > 1. $\frac{1}{z(e^{\frac{1}{z}}+1)}$
> > 2. $\frac{1}{(z^2+1)(z-1)^2}-\frac{1}{4(z-i)}$

OK, so I think the first is the easier (perhaps). There's clearly an essential singularity at the origin caused by the exponential. However, I think there are also singularities where $e^{\frac{1}{z}}=-1$, which occurs when $z=\frac{1}{(2n+1) \pi}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, though I am not sure how to classify there. Help with that would be very appreciated.

For the second, we can split it into $\frac{1}{4(z+i)}-\frac{1}{2(z-1)}+\frac{1}{2(z-1)^2}$, which makes the position of the poles clear; at $-i, 1$. Is it the case that the pole at $-i$ is simple, and the pole at $1$ is a double pole. That seems to be the case.

Any help/verification would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of the second exercise is correct. The partial fractions indicate, as you said, that $-i$ is a pole of first order, while $1$ is a pole of order $2$. The term $-\frac{1}{2(z-1)}$ does not matter because there is the one with $-\frac{1}{2(z-1)^\color{red}{2}}$.

Concerning the first one, you are also right about the essential singularity. The factor $z$ is too weak to counteract $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$.

You can then do a power series expansion around, for example, $z=\frac{1}{i\pi}$ of $e^\frac{1}{z}$. It starts

$$e^\frac{1}{z} = -1 - \pi^2(z-\frac{1}{i\pi}) \ldots$$

The $-1$ is countered by the $+1$, then you can factor out $(z-\frac{1}{i\pi})$ and get a pole of first order. Because of the periodicity, all $\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi i}$ are then poles of first order.

Comment: I am not so sure about that removable singularity of $\frac{1}{e^\frac{1}{z}}$. I thought about it with Picard's great theorem, and when $e^\frac{1}{z}$ takes almost every value in every neighborhood of $0$, then $\frac{1}{e^\frac{1}{z}}$ should too.

Comment: Gregor, you're right.  I was mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $0$ is **not** an *isolated singularity* in 1). The classification into removable singularities, poles and essential singularities are usually only defined for isolated singularities. (If you're not convinced, what kind of singularity would $\sqrt{z}$ have at the origin?)